# Request Stats printer for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, profiling, rack, middleware

For every request , rails, by default, logs time spent in views/active_record(sql), active resource http requests, etc. For e.g.

```
Started GET "/blah" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Jun 07 19:07:33 +0530 2012   
Processing by Some::Controller#someaction as HTML   Parameters: { "id"=>"31550"}
GET http://somedomain:80/somepath/users.json?some=thing&and=something
--> 200 OK 594 (119.9ms)
Rendered a/b/c/_d.html.haml (1.3ms) 
Rendered x/y/z/_w.html.haml (2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3529ms (Views: 345.3ms | ActiveRecord:3.0ms)
```

Production logs can be quite jumbled when parallel requests come in, and viewing/parsing logs is no simple task and often doesn't work.

Is there a rack/rails middleware that can give me these numbers for my production setup on a per request basis. Something like [rack-perftools_profiler](https://github.com/bhb/rack-perftools_profiler) but giving me the numbers/stats found in rails logs(example above) ?

rack-perftools_profiler prints profiling data masking the actual response from the request and I can selectively do that by using the url param 'profile=true' for any URL.